# Proof of local triviality of the vector bundle $\gamma_n^{1}$ for the base space $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, characteristic-classes

Milnor defines the total space of $\gamma_n^1$ as follows

> Let $E\left(\gamma_n^1\right)$ be the subset of $P^n \times R^{n+1}$ consisting of all pairs $(\{\pm x\}, v)$ such that the vector $v$ is a multiple of $x$. Define $\pi: E\left(\gamma_n^1\right) \rightarrow P^n$ by $\pi(\{\pm x\}, v)=\{\pm x\}$. Thus each fiber $\pi^{-1}(\{\pm x\})$ can be identified with the line through $x$ and $-x$ in $R^{n+1}$. Each such line is to be given its usual vector space structure. The resulting vector bundle $\gamma_{\mathrm{n}}^1$ will be called the canonical line bundle over $\mathrm{P}^{\mathrm{n}}$.

I am studying Milnor's Characteristic classes.
While trying to prove that the vector bundle $\gamma_{n}^{1}$  is locally trivial (for the base space $\mathbb{P}^n$), it claims that:

\begin{equation}
h : U \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \pi^{-1}(U) \\
 (\{\pm x\}, t) \mapsto (\{\pm x\}, tx) 
\end{equation}

is a homeomorphism. I can feel that it is a homeomorphism but I am having a hard time proving it explicitly.

My Attempt:

Clearly, $h$ is continuous where $h (a,b) = (h_1 (a,b), h_2(a,b))$ where bothe $h_1$ and $h_2$ are continuous. Also, easy to show that it is bijective. But how do I show that the inverse function is continuous?

Comment: Compute the formula for the inverse. Or compute the Jacobian of the map itself

Comment: I no longer possess the book. I presume Milnor did not write it quite this way. Is he choosing a small enough $U$ that he can specify which point in $S^n$ is $x$ and which is $-x$? Has he made such a specification?

Comment: @TedShifrin, I have the book. He defines projective space as the set of antipodal pairs of points on the unit sphere. Here, $U$ is an open set contained in a hemisphere.

Comment: Great, @Deane, but then $U$ is not literally a subset of $\Bbb P^n$ as is needed for a bundle trivialization. That is, $x\in U\subset S^n$ and $\{\pm x\}\in p(U)\subset \Bbb P^n$. But he writes $\{\pm x\}$ as a point of $U$, which is clearly not a point of a hemisphere. It’s not like me to be so pedantic, but this is confusing for beginners.

Comment: @TedShifrin, you’re right and I erred. $U$ is in fact a subset of projective space. I misunderstood the notation.

Comment: But then why is $tx$ meaningful? There have to be words the OP has perhaps omitted.

Comment: @TedShifrin, $tx$ is in the fiber above the point $\{-x,x\}$. If you restrict $x$ to a subset $V$ of the open hemisphere and let $U$ be the set of points $\{x,-x\}$, where $x\in V$, then there is no ambiguity in the formulas.

Comment: @Deane Of course. All this was omitted in the OP.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Milnor uncharacteristically explains this rather unclearly.

Answer (score 1):

Milnor starts the proof as follows

> Proof that $\gamma_{\mathrm{n}}^1$ is locally trivial. Let $\mathrm{U} \subset \mathrm{S}^{\mathrm{n}}$ be any open set that is small enough so as to contain no pair of antipodal points, and let $U_1$ denote the image of $U$ in $P^n$. Then a homeomorphism
> $$
> \mathrm{h}: \mathrm{U}_1 \times \mathrm{R} \rightarrow \pi^{-1}\left(U_1\right)
> $$
> is defined by the requirement that
> $$
> h(\{\pm x\}, t)=(\{\pm x\}, t x)
> .$$

As in $U_1$ we have a well defined section $s:U_1 \to U$ given by $s(\{\pm x\})=x$. Define the inverse of $h$ to be the map $f:\pi^{-1}\left(U_1\right)\to  \mathrm{U}_1 \times \mathrm{R}$ defined by
$$(\{\pm x\}, v) \mapsto (\{\pm x\}, \langle  s(\{\pm x\}), v\rangle),$$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is ordinary inner product on $\mathrm{R}^n$. This map is continuous as it is the composition of continuous maps. Its also the inverse of $h$ as
$$f\circ h((\{\pm x\},t))=f\left(\{\pm x\},ts\left(\{\pm x\}\right)\right)=\left(\{\pm x\},\langle  s(\{\pm x\}), ts\left(\{\pm x\}\right)\rangle\right)=(\{\pm x\},t).$$
The last equality is derived from the fact that $s(\{\pm x\}) \in S^{n}$, thus $\langle  s(\{\pm x\}), s\left(\{\pm x\}\right)\rangle=1.$